# how to use gulp-filter with main-bower-files to filter on directory in the middle

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-filter

I want to filter just the files which include the directory ui-router somewhere in the middle of the path.

I have the following code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');


var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');


gulp.task('default',function() {
    var bower_files = mainBowerFiles();
    var js_filter = gulpFilter(['**/*.js']);

    gulp.src(bower_files)
        .pipe(js_filter)
        .pipe(debug({title: 'unicorn:'}))

    var js_filter = gulpFilter(['**/ui-router/**']);

    gulp.src(bower_files)
        .pipe(js_filter)
        .pipe(debug({title: 'unicorn1:'}))
});
```

The output is:

> [12:10:53] unicorn: bower_components\ngstorage\ngStorage.js
>
> [12:10:53] unicorn: bower_components\ui-router\release\angular-ui-router.js
>
> [12:10:53] unicorn: bower_components\x2js\xml2json.min.js [12:10:53]
>
> unicorn1: 0 items

Meaning that `['**/*.js']` works to filter out all js files.

But `['**/ui-router/**']` does not work. What is problematic with this pattern?

I read the following doc https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob and i don't see why it should not work.

Comment: You want everything in the ui-router folder? Shouldn't it be `**/ui-router/*` ? Or if you have subdirectories in your ui-router folder : `**/ui-router/**/*`

Comment: These options don't work either

Comment: Could you set the second filter as var jsfilter2 ? Just in case it keeps it as reference.. You are right, I don't think this has anything to do with your pattern. This should work. But your second usage of `jsfilter` scares me a bit..

Comment: It was a stupid issue with gulp-filter. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the result of main-bower-files:

```
var files = mainBowerFiles(/\/ui\-router\//);
```

Answer (score 0):

After hacking with this a long time i found the issue.
In gulp-filter the vinyl file.relative property is sent.[Comment from Sindre Sorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter/issues/20#issuecomment-48797091)

In our case the files are without globs(What i understand) and therefore we get just the name of the file without the directory.

The solution is to write instead of  `gulp.src(bower_files)`  `gulp.src(bower_files,{base:__dirname})`

Here we say gulp from where to start the relative file.